# Yii2 format date in a query

Tags: yii2

I need to format a date -week_end- from yyyy-mm-dd to M-d-Y. to populate a dropdown list.
Here is the controller code:

```
public static function getPayWeeks()
{
    $droptions = PayWeeks::find()->asArray()->all();
    return ArrayHelper::map($droptions, 'id', 'week_end');
}
```

Here is the form code:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'payweek-form']); ?>
     <?= $form->field($model, 'id')->dropDownList(PayWeeks::getPayWeeks(), ['prompt' => ' -- Select Week End Date --']); ?> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'contact-button']) ?>
            </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reformat the `week_end` field when creating the array:

```
public static function getPayWeeks()
{
    $droptions = PayWeeks::find()->asArray()->all();
    return ArrayHelper::map($droptions, 'id', function($model) {
        return date("M-d-Y", strtotime($model['week_end']));
    });
}
```

Comment: I got the following error:  A non well formed numeric value encountered

Comment: Sorry I had forgotten to call `strtotime`, I just updated my answer

Comment: I was just about to comment.  Thanks for the answer.